# meta property is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom, metadata

i have some code which takes in a html using ajax and after which it's meta tags are retrieved.

```
if (request.readyState == 4) { 
    var html_text = request.responseText; 
    var parent = document.createElement('div'); 
    parent.innerHTML = html_text; 

    var metas = parent.getElementsByTagName('meta'); 
    var meta; 

    for(var i=0; i < metas.length; i++) { 
        meta = metas[i]; 
        alert(meta.property); 
        alert(meta.content); } 
    }
```

the html_text does contains meta property and content and the content does show. but why is the meta property showing as undefined? can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Meta tags normally contain name and content. Where is property coming form?

Comment: @epascarello thanks for your reply. i was testing something out like the html code from a youtube site when a video is playing. the meta data there has a property and content.when i do the alert(meta.content) it has response in it. however, the meta property returns undefined. I am referring to the ones below those with the name.

Answer (score 1):

Either you have to look for `meta.name` or you could use `meta.getAttribute("property")`.

btw: You are innerHTML'ing the variable `html_code` but you stored the HTML content in `html_text`.

Comment: opps. sorry. but it is correct on my side, i changed it already. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using getAttribute to get the property attribute:

```
alert(meta.getAttribute('property'));
```

I'm not sure why it wouldn't work your way though.

Answer (score 0):

What you try here is a kind of creation of a new document, it will not work at least in IE this way.
Put this line

```
alert(parent.innerHTML)
```

right after:

```
parent.innerHTML = html_text;
```

...and you will see, that you only get the contents of the body, everything else has been omitted.

If the response is valid xml, `request.responseXML` should be available, you can inspect it directly(it's already a document).